# Asp.Net Core MVC RC-1 validation doesn't show up when javascript is disabled

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form that has the need to work even when JavaScript is disabled, and I have to validate this form, I have a tag helper for it like so:

```
<span asp-validation-for="ContactName" class="text-danger" />
```

And in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ContactViewModel contact)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(contact);
        }
         // do something
     }
```

Here is my view model:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ContactDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="پر کردن این فیلد الزامی میباشد.")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage ="حداکثر تعداد کراکتر برای این فیلد نمیتواند بیشتر از صد باشد.")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "پر کردن این فیلد الزامی میباشد.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="لطفا یک ایمیل معتبر وارد کنید.")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "حداکثر تعداد کراکتر برای این فیلد نمیتواند بیشتر از صد باشد.")]

    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "پر کردن این فیلد الزامی میباشد.")]
    [MaxLength(4000, ErrorMessage = "حداکثر تعداد کراکتر برای این فیلد نمیتواند بیشتر از چهار هزار باشد.")]
    public string ContactBody { get; set; }

    [Range(1000000000, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "لطفا یک شماره تلفن معتبر وارد نمایید.")]
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the tag helper for validation, the validation message doesn't show below the textbox if validation fail, but when I use the old Html helpers like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactName)
```

It works, I wanted to know if it's by design or is it a bug? Also Worth to note that validation summary tag helper works if I set its `asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All"`, but I want a validation message for individual text box on the form, any though?

Comment: Why do you return a view in case of invalid model and Json when the model is valid ? It's weird ! How do you call this method from the client side ?

Comment: It is not pertinent to the current problem, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that

```
<span asp-validation-for="Model.Name" class="text-danger"/>
```

will not render unless you add the jquery-validation js to the page.
In MVC Core, you will have to add it by calling

```
   @section Scripts {
     @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    }
```

The partial view _validationScriptsPartial has this markup

```
<environment names="Development">
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

client side validation can't work without javascript, you must also do server side validation so that it works with or without javascript

ie on the server you check if the model is valid and if not return the user back to the same view

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not including my controller code in my question, I already did that, I'm aware of the difference between the two, but the html helper version works for both (client and sever side), but tag helper doesn't.

Comment: ok but show your model, does it have any actual validation attributes? Also you are returning json not a view which seems weird since you said no javascript. If you are returning json typically you are returning it based on a client side javascript ajax call to the server, in that case you would have to use client side javascript to respond to the json result, you can't just sometimes return a view and other times return json, that seems weird

Comment: I edited the question with the view model, and this has nothing to do with returning json, if the validation failed, I return a view, if not json, I have some logic to use ajax if JavaScript was enabled and use normal post if it was disabled, but it is irrelevant , the same thing happen if I return a normal view without any json or anything, I edited the question, validation does not work with current code in controller's action.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see what the state of the model is on postback?

Comment: Similar code does work as expected for me so there has to be something about your code that is not quite right

Comment: Did you do it with JavaScript disabled? by not working I mean the validation fail, the model state is not valid and form doesn't submit, but the validation errors doesn't show up, I guess I'll have to stick to the html helpers for now, thanks anyway.

Comment: yes, for example if I use the use the standard new project template with individual users ie with identity, the registration page shows validation errors even if I use Firefox with the noscript plugin enabled so that no js can execute I still see the validation messages, same as in my own custom projects it works without js enabled. I can't help but think those things you say are not relevant to the problem are indeed relevant, you should use different method names for ajax posts and regular posts.